# python pandas groupby eventType and eventId and get date diff between each eventType

Tags: python, pandas

My data format is the following:

```
    id  eventSource        eventType                           timestamp
0  102    sensor1          received                   2021-10-06 13:45:51
1  102    sensor1          startingCalculation        2021-10-06 13:45:55
2  102    sensor1          endedCalculation           2021-10-06 13:46:00
3  103    sensor2          received                   2021-10-06 13:46:00
4  103    sensor2          startingCalculation        2021-10-06 13:46:04
5  103    sensor2          endedCalculation           2021-10-06 13:46:10
```

I need help with the following task:

I want to group by the Id eventSource and eventType and show diffs between the `received` and `endedCalculation` events for each of them like so:

```
    id   eventSource         diff 
0  102      sensor1           9
0  103      sensor2           10
```

And so on ...

I am kind of stuck in the groupby stage,

Thank you for anyone trying to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
m=df['eventType'].isin(['received','endedCalculation'])
#created a boolean mask
```

Finally pass that mask and use `groupby()` and `agg()` method:

```
out=df[m]
out['diff']=out.groupby(['id','eventSource'])['timestamp'].diff().dt.total_seconds()
out=out.dropna(subset=['diff']).drop('eventType',1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

output of `out`:

```
    id  eventSource     timestamp               diff
0   102     sensor1     2021-10-06 13:46:00     9.0
1   103     sensor2     2021-10-06 13:46:10     10.0
```

Comment: Hey, I tried your solution and i get the error : "Function does not reduce"
also, i originally have another field that i group by, is it the reason I get the error ?

Comment: yes if you have added other field in groupby that may caused the error

Comment: ok so I have 2 fields that I group by, what do I do to make it work ?

Comment: I thought that it wouldn't matter, but one sec let me edit my question

Comment: @Eitank Updated answer...Kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: updated answer friend kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233619/discussion-between-eitank-and-anurag-dabas).